# WPF: getting AccessText in ScrollViewer to wrap

Tags: wpf, user-interface, xaml, text, scrollviewer

I have a `Grid` containing a `ScrollViewer` containing `AccessText`.  I want the `AccessText` to take up the full width of the `ScrollViewer`, which should take up the full width of the `Grid`, without any overflow.  Currently, the contents of my `AccessText` are cut off on the right side of the screen instead of wrapping.  I have tried setting `AccessText.TextWrapping` to `Wrap`, `WrapWithOverflow`, and I've also tried removing the property entirely.  I switched to using a `Grid` instead of a `StackPanel` because I thought that might affect how the contents are sized, but that hasn't helped.  Here's what I have:

```
<Grid MaxHeight="40">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Whee a label:" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <AccessText Text="{Binding MyLongTextField}"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set ColumnDefinition Width to Auto, the ScrollViewer within it won't be limited by the "visible Width" of the Column, so it will still take up as much horizontal space as it needs. With the xaml you posted, I think `Width="*"` will suit your needs. For the ScrollViewer, it seems like you don't want it to be able to Scroll horizontaly but only verticaly? In that case, set `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"`. Otherwise you'll get a Horizontal ScrollBar.

```
<Grid MaxHeight="40">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Whee a label:" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <AccessText TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding MyLongTextField}"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This looks like a step in the right direction.  Changing the `Width` to `*` caused a horizontal scrollbar to show up, allowing me to see all the text.  Setting `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` to `Disabled` though takes away all scrollbars, and the text is once again cut off.  :(

Comment: @Sarah Check out my answer as it will remove the ScrollViewer which I assumed you did not need.

Comment: @Sarah Vessels: Even with TextWrapping="Wrap" set on the AccessText?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want the `AccessText` to wrap indefinitely, modify your second `ColumnDefinition` from `Auto` to `*` and move the `AccessText` outside of the `ScrollViewer` as seen below...

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <TextBlock Text="Whee a label:" Grid.Column="0"/>
             <AccessText Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding MyLongTextField}"/>
    </Grid>
```

The reason the text would not wrap is because the second `ColumnDefinition` was set to `Auto`; which essentially does not force a bounds around the `AccessText`.

If you want to keep the `ScrollViewer` try this...

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Whee a label:" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <AccessText  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding MyLongTextField}"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: If I do this and then decrease the `MaxHeight` on the `Grid`, no scrollbars appear to let me scroll to see all the text.

Comment: @Sarah You either have scrollbars or you have to let the height increase so the text can wrap as needed as the wrapping text will require an increased height.

Comment: I want a vertical scrollbar, no horizontal scrollbar, and I want the text to wrap such that a vertical scrollbar is displayed as necessary.

Comment: @Sarah Added additional info when using ScrollViewer

Answer (score 0):

This ended up giving me what I wanted:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Whee a label:" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" MaxHeight="40"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <AccessText Text="{Binding CRData.Error}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Thanks to [Meleak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596194/wpf-getting-accesstext-in-scrollviewer-to-wrap/4596440#4596440) and [Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596194/wpf-getting-accesstext-in-scrollviewer-to-wrap/4596448#4596448) for the suggestion of using `*` for the column width instead of `Auto`, and to Meleak for suggesting `Disabled` for the horizontal scrollbar instead of `Auto`.

Comment: That looks exactly like the answer that I gave you or am I missing something? :)